# Parse async method of retrieving data in C#, how to access the data

Tags: c#, android, parse-platform, xamarin

Im trying to retrieve a simple query on parse and add the content on a custom adapter but i can figure it how, i see from the documentation that only with async i can get the data, but how i can add the data after to the adapter if the async method always return void? This is what im trying and is not working

```
public class BusinessListFragment : Fragment
{
    private List<Business> _list;
    ListView businessListView;

    public async override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        _list = await GetData();
    }
    public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.BusinessList, container, false);
        businessListView = view.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.businessListView);
        var adapter = new BusinessListAdapter(Activity, _list);
        businessListView.Adapter = adapter;
        adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged ();

        return view;
    }
    public async Task<List<Business>> GetData(){

        var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Business");
        IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = await query.FindAsync();
        var data = new List<Business>();

        foreach (var temp in results)
        {
            var _business = new Business();

            // This does not require a network access.
            _business.Name = temp.Get<string>("name");
            _business.Address = temp.Get<string>("address");
            _business.Town = temp.Get<string>("town");
            _business.Country = temp.Get<string>("country");
            data.Add (_business);
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong? It should be something pretty simple

Comment: I think the (adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged ();) belongs at the bottom of your (async void GetData(){) so as you (_list.Add (_business);) you then notify the adapter has changed - but im not 100% sure. Im running ( foreach (var temp in results)) loop and thats where i have the (adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged ();) in my code, just below it

Comment: the adapter is defined on OnCreateView how i can access it on GetData? also this shouldn't be a problem, im just notifying the adapter later i think

Comment: Sorry i didn't see the C# :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that i doesn't have to return the data, i can recreate and populate the adapter withing my GetData() method in this way:

```
Activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>{
        var adapter = new BusinessListAdapter(Activity, data);
        businessListView.Adapter = adapter;
        adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            Console.WriteLine ("name="+data.Count.ToString());
        });
```

Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't generally need to use explicit Task methods with async and await - they were introduced to C# specifically to simplify this sort of issue.

```
public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.BusinessList, container, false);
        businessListView = view.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.businessListView);

        _list = await GetData();

        var adapter = new BusinessListAdapter(Activity, _list);
        businessListView.Adapter = adapter;
        adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged ();

        return view;
    }

    public async Task<List<Business>> GetData(){

        var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Business");
        IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = await query.FindAsync();
        var data = new List<Business>();

        foreach (var temp in results)
        {
            var _business = new Business();

            // This does not require a network access.
            _business.Name = temp.Get<string>("name");
            _business.Address = temp.Get<string>("address");
            _business.Town = temp.Get<string>("town");
            _business.Country = temp.Get<string>("country");
            data.Add (_business);
        }

      return data;
    }
```

Comment: thanks but how i can use the await operator on public override View OnCreateView?

Comment: you should be able to just add the async keyword to OnCreateView

Comment: its an override method, it must have the same properties as the original
For this: "public async override Task<View> OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)"
i get "C:\..\BusinessListFragment.cs(36,36): Error CS0508: 'BusinessListFragment.OnCreateView(Android.Views.LayoutInflater, Android.Views.ViewGroup, Android.OS.Bundle)': return type must be 'Android.Views.View' to match overridden member 'Android.App.Fragment.OnCreateView(Android.Views.LayoutInflater, Android.Views.ViewGroup, Android.OS.Bundle)'"

Comment: Sorry, that would have worked on a void method.  You could move the data call to a lifecycle method that can be made async, like OnResume

Comment: I cant do that on Resume because this needs override too and i get this:
"C:\\BusinessListFragment.cs(33,33): Error CS0507: 'BusinessListFragment.OnResume()': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'public' inherited member 'Android.App.Fragment.OnResume()' (CS0507)" if i use this "protected async override void OnResume()"

Comment: Why are you changing public to protected?  Just add 'async' and leave the rest the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89533/discussion-between-cdrosos-and-jason).